# How can I set the value of my HTML button?

Tags: html

I have tried the following

```
<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple" value="MyText">
```

However the text on my button still reads 'Choose Files'.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values uses for Text input purpose.Buttons input type is Submit.You can use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

Value only works for text inputs, buttons and input with a type of sumbit, you really can't tweak the input type file without some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Input type="file" is pre-defined by the browser. You can't change it but if you want to try, there is a good article here.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html